# Equivalence of countability, surjection $f:\mathbb{N} \to A$ and injection $g:A \to \mathbb{N} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Regarding the following proof I'd like to know

Let $A$ be a non-empty set. Then the following are equivalent.

(a) $A$ is countable.

(b) There exists a surjection $f : \mathbb{N} → A.$

(c) There exists an injection $g : A → \mathbb{N}.$

$(b) ⇒ (c)$ Assume that $f : \mathbb{N} → A$ is a surjection. We claim that there is an injection $g: A → \mathbb{N}.$ To deﬁne g note that if $a ∈ A$, then $f^{-1}(\{a\})\neq  ∅.$ Hence we set $g(a) = min  f^{-1}(\{a\})$. Now note that if $a \neq a′$, then the sets $f^{-1}(\{a\}) ∩ f^{-1}(\{a′\}) = ∅$ which implies $min^{-1}(\{a\}) \neq min^{-1}(\{a′\})$. Hence $g(a) \neq  g(a′)$ and $g : A →\mathbb{N}$ is an injective.

why $f(\{a\})$ takes a set (e.g. the set containing $a$ ) as an argument. Why not $a$ alone? It's said nowhere that $A$ is a set of sets.
Also how can $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{a′\})$ be disjunct, if we only assume $f$ is a surjective and therefore two elements of $A$ could map to the same element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Where you wrote $f(\{a\})$ originally, it was supposed to be $f^{-1}(\{a\})$.  I've changed your post accordingly

Comment: When you ask *"
 why $f(\{a\})$ takes a set (e.g. the set containing $a$ ) as an argument"*, do you mean to ask "
 why $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ takes a set as an argument"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake, the reverse function was meant. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:A \to B$ is a bijection, then it is common to talk about the *inverse map* $f^{-1}:B \to A$.  This is **not** the sense in which $f^{-1}$ is used.  In particluar, $f^{-1}$ is really being used as the *"preimage"* map from $\mathcal P(B)$ to $\mathcal P(A)$, with the definition
$$
f^{-1}(S) = \{a \in A : f(a) \in S\}
$$
There is clearly a connection between this definition and the usual one.  In particular: when $f$ is injective, we have $f^{-1}(\{f(a)\}) = \{a\}$.

With this in mind, perhaps you can make sense of the proof.

---

Now, suppose that $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap f^{-1}(\{a'\}) \neq \emptyset$, and that $n$ is an element of this intersection.  By the definition of the first set, we have $f(n) = a$.  By the definition of the second set, $f(n) = a'$.  This would mean that $f:\Bbb N \to A$ fails to be a function, since we have associated two outputs with the same input.

Comment: It is also common to define
$$
f(S) = \{f(a) : a \in S\}
$$
and we would say that $f:A \to B$ *induces* a map from $\mathcal P(A)$ to $\mathcal P(B)$.  However, it is rare that authors will differentiate between these two (related but different) uses of $f$ once $f:A \to B$ is established.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I still don't understand how $f^{-1}(\{a\}) ∩ f^{-1}(\{a′\}) = ∅$ can be, when it's only known $f$ is a surjective. for such a function, couldn't the preimages of two different elements still contain a shared element?

Comment: No; that would mean that $f$ fails to be a function.  See my latest edit.

Comment: Oh okay, a relation is considered a (total) function only iff its left-total and single-valued. Thanks for pointing out. Now I fully understand the proof.